# Different column view for Folders vs Files in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, view, versioning

I have a document library that contains 4 folders. Each folder contains files that need to be approved or rejected. Therefore, I have versioning settings turned on so I can capture approvals in the "Approval Status" column.

At the folder view, this column does not make sense to show since folders shouldn't have an approval status.  Is there a way I can hide this column from the folder viewpoint but not when viewing the files within the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how SharePoint document libraries work. When you add a column in document library view, it is added at library level & not folder/file level.

So, if you change any library view settings (like grouping/filters/sorting), change will be applied at document library level & not folder/file level.

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to hide the column for particular content types (folder/file).