# Different format for sub folders in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, view, folder

Is it possible to create a different format for sub-folder within the same document library?

For example, have one sub-folder with tiles and then the following sub-folders they click into from that page would be a list format

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

The views in library are created at document library level and not at folder/subfolder level.

So, if you change any library view settings (like list/tile format or filtering/sorting, etc.), the change will be applied at all levels (library, folders and subfolders).

Hence, you cannot have different view format for folders and subfolders.

**Similar thread**: [Different column view for Folders vs Files in Document Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299171/different-column-view-for-folders-vs-files-in-document-library/299172#299172)